# How to add signature on a interactive pdf using adobe acrobat xi pro?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

How to add signature on a interactive pdf using adobe acrobat xi pro ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find signature options in the menu pane that defaults to the right side of Acrobat. From Tools|Fill&Sign|Comment, select Fill&Sign, and then select "Place Signature" from the menu pane below it. You will be prompted to create a new signature.